# Generate html report in Protractor even if there is an exception/error in code

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter" package for generating html reports for my protractor test cases. This is only generating reports for passed/failed specs but when there is a timeout/compilation error in between, it does not capture anything in the report at all. It shows as:

Total specs tested: 0
Total failed: 0

Is there anyway I can see the report for the specs which ran successfully before it throws exception?

Could someone please help me on this?